# search with part of each word like ios mysql

Tags: mysql

For Example I Want To Search In Column X For client name And The Client Name is "Yosef Atef Farouck" And When I Search With Query `SELECT * FROM clients WHERE name LIKE '%Yosef Atef Farouck%'` I Got The Result But If I Want To Search With Only First Character Of Each Word Like "Yos At Faro" Or Like "Yos Farou"

Is that Possible ?

I Have Tried Too Many Ideas But I Didn't Get What I Won't Yet

Comment: WHERE name LIKE '%Yos%' AND name LIKE '%Farou%'

Comment: that's great idea thank u 

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
SELECT * 
FROM clients
WHERE name LIKE '%Yos% At% Faro%'
```

Comment: "Your Common Sense" solution is working fine for me Thank u SelVazi for your interest 